# unicode.txt slowness

Tags: microsoft-windows, text-editing, unicode, performance

Moving around point (using the cursor keys) in Xah’s [unicode.txt](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/unicode.txt) in `fundamental-mode` is noticeably slower than in an ordinary text file. *Are the many non-ASCII characters the issue? Anything else?*

About: GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2017-04-24 started with option `-Q`

Comment: I can see all characters and I do not have slow downs, neither in `text-mode` nor `fundamental-mode`. I'm using 24.5 GTK with Linux. How are you moving point, by keyboard input?

Comment: https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/issues/273 see if this is relevant.

Comment: I see no problem on OSX either using Emacs 25.2.1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reading the [GitHub discussion thread](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/issues/273) linked in @wvxvw’s comment, I discovered the variable `inhibit-compacting-font-caches`. Setting it to non-nil solves the issue:

```
(setq inhibit-compacting-font-caches t)
```

Now navigating point is fast. According to the variable’s documentation, inhibiting compacting font caches comes at the expense of more memory usage, which is fine for me.

See also [bug 27350](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=27350) filed by @Drew.

Comment: You can accept your own answer (or any other answer, if you want to wait for others).

Comment: I just filed an enhancement request (bug #[27350](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=27350)) to make the variable customizable.

Comment: I also filed bug #[30539](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=30539), which is similar - involves slowness due to the same variable.

Comment: Thanks that really works for me too.

Comment: Still works for Emacs 26 Win 64