# Difficulty inserting current weather with org-roam dailies template

Tags: org-capture, shell-command

I am trying to get the current weather inserted into my org roam dailies.
Here is the default capture template I'm starting with, from
https://systemcrafters.net/build-a-second-brain-in-emacs/keep-a-journal/
It seems to work quite well:

```
 (org-roam-dailies-capture-templates
    '(("d" "default" entry "* %<%I:%M %p>: %?"
       :if-new (file+head "%<%Y-%m-%d>.org" "#+title: %<%Y-%m-%d>\n"))))
```

I have installed the key bindings and key maps recommended in that site,
too.  Everything works well.

Next I add this function to my init.el:

```
  (defun org-roam-weather (current-node-ignored)
      "Return local weather as a string for org-roam capture."
    (shell-command-to-string "curl 'https://wttr.in?0T' 2>/dev/null"))
```

Then I replace the template lines above with

```
(org-roam-dailies-capture-templates
 '(("d" "default" entry "* %<%I:%M %p>\n${org-roam-weather}\n%?"
    :if-new (file+head "%<%Y-%m-%d>.org" "#+title: %<%Y-%m-%d>\n"))))
```

After doing so, and restarting emacs, I find that input in the window
opened by org-roam-dailies-capture-today is really slow.  The weather
is inserted but input slows to a crawl until I close the capture window.  Any idea how I can fix it?

Bonus question: should I maybe wrap the ascii art in a begin/end
environment?  I imagine I will seldom export dailies, but if I ever do
so, it maybe makes sense to mark the region as monospace ascii art.

UPDATE: For some reason, the editing mode just does not like the wind direction arrow in the output from wttr.in .  If I delete that one character, everything seems to speed up again.  I do believe I have all my UTF-8, etc., settings correct (the arrow displays correctly, for example, except it has a box around it in Emacs that it doesn't have in the shell) but I will look again.  wttr.in probably has a setting to simplify the character set, too.

As for wrapping the ascii art output, it seems #+begin_example/#+end_example is the right thing to do but I feel like it's overkill unless I decide to export a daily some day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question.  Place the line

```
(setq inhibit-compacting-font-caches t)
```

in init.el.  See the discussion at [unicode.txt slowness](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33510/unicode-txt-slowness).

In addition, as mentioned in my question, I may decide to wrap the ASCII art in #+begin_example and #+end_example if I decide to export a daily, but until then I feel it is less cluttered without the environment.

And in case you are interested, I improved the dailies capture template including current date, time, topic, location, and weather:

```
(org-roam-dailies-capture-templates
 '(("d" "default" entry "* %<%Y-%m-%d> %<%I:%M %p>: %^{Topic}\n${org-roam-weather}\n%?"
    :if-new (file+head "%<%Y-%m-%d>.org" "#+title: %<%Y-%m-%d>\n"))))
```